# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was thinking that $\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)}>=\sqrt[n]{n^n}=n$ and $\frac{1}{n}\cdot n=1\neq{0}$ so it is divergent. But I'm not sure if it is the right way to solve it.

Comment: What you have done is fine.

Comment: Your way is a correct one , to complete it you should emphasis that if the  $n$th term doesn't tend to zero then the series is divergent

Comment: You are right. Since $a_n$ does not approach 0 as $n \to \infty$, we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ does not converge. Note that this is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a sum to converge.